# Division in ColorBox not loading twice with JS 1.10.2

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Our site is upgrading it's jquery to 1.10.2 and since we have previously used colorbox this is presenting a few challenges. Primarily, the issue that I'm seeing is that when a user clicks a link to open colorbox with the intention of loading a division, it works fine the first time, but the second time colorbox displays only a white page. I've been debugging but I can't see the difference between any of the settings when it runs the first time and when it runs the second. If the page is reloaded, the window will open normally again first time, fail second.

Here is the button that calls the colorbox window:

```
   $('#btn_Detail').click(function (e) {
       $('#div_Detail input:text').val('');
       $('#div_Detail input:radio:checked').removeAttr('checked');
       $('#div_Detail select').val('');
       $('#div_Detail textarea').val('');

       if ($('#hid_ID').val() != '') {
             $.colorbox({ href: '#div_Detail', width: '650px', height: '300px', inline: true });
       }
   }
```

And here is the division that it's opening:

```
   <div id="div_Detail">
    <div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label>Type<span class="req">*</span></label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Detail_Type" runat="server" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>ID<span class="req">*</span><em>(Make,Model,Serial #, Vin #,Building #)</em></label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Detail_Id" runat="server" style="overflow:visible;" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Description:<span class="req">*</span></label>
            <asp:TextBox TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="2" ID="txt_Detail_Desc" Width="300px" runat="server" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Damage:<span class="req">*</span></label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDamage" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Owning Property</label>
            <input type="text" id="txt_OwnMaterial" name="txt_OwnMaterial" style="overflow:visible;" />
            <a id="a_OwnMaterial" href="#"><img alt="" src="/images/TinyButton.gif" /></a>
            <input type="hidden" id="hid_ActOwnMaterialID" name="txt_ActOwnMaterial" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Owned By<span class="req">*</span></label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Detail_OwnBy" runat="server" />
        </li>
    </ul>
    <asp:Button ID="btn_AddUpdate" runat="server" CssClass="yes_btn cancel" Text="Add"  />
    </div>
```

There have been some additional tweaks to the colorbox script itself to make it compliant with jquery 1.10.2. Specifically changing the $.event.trigger() lines inside the script along with a couple of minor other things. Could someone please give me some insight as to how I can trouble shoot this to find the problem?

There's a possible theory that the colorbox is removing the division from the page when it runs the first time and so when the user goes to get it the second time it no longer exists. Is it in memory some where, can it be retrieved from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help, the answer has been stumbled upon and it has to do with the trigger function inside of the ColorBox script. In the old ColorBox script the event.trigger call has been deprecated and so the script had to be changed to specifically call those items that needed a trigger. This happens to be one of them so to fix the issue we added the following line to the trigger function in the colorbox.js file:

$('[id*=cbox]', $div).add($div).trigger(event);